# Where is the documentation for Symfony 1.4 Templating Component?

Tags: documentation, symfony-1.4, templating

I'm using an old component of Symfony 1.4 called Templating. I'm searching the documentation (API reference).

I search, and found an [example](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/components/templating/trunk/lib/sfTemplateHelperJavascripts.php) of Component Templating.

This appears to be the documentation, but was [REDIRECT to new 2.0 version](https://www.google.com.co/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22sfTemplateHelperJavascripts%20class%22) (result API | sfTemplateHelperJavascripts Class | Symfony Templating ).

I don't want to use the version 2.0 or Twig templates. I'm performing a maintenance of an old big system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony Components are now part of Symfony 2.0, that's why it redirects to the current website.

Anyway, thanks to web.archive.org, you [can still access the old Symfony Component website](http://web.archive.org/web/20101004223616/http://components.symfony-project.org/templating/documentation). And see the documentation for the Templating (api, etc ..).

Comment: -1 for symfony developers. It is a sin to erase the documentation of a free software product.